# Using JavaScript, how do I change the CSS style of one element based on the CSS style of another element?

Tags: javascript, css, conditional-statements

I'm trying to change the height of one div depending on the opacity/visibility of another div.  It seems like this should be pretty simple, but nothing I try seems to work.

I was thinking it would go something like this:

```
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var green = document.getElementById("green");

if(red.style.opacity = "0"){
green.style.height = "200px";
}
```

But that just changes both the opacity and the height without actually checking what the opacity was to begin with.

Any suggestions as how to achieve the functionality I'm after would be much appreciated!

Comment: `red.style.opacity == "0"`

Comment: `if (red.style.opacity === "0")` is what you're looking for, only one `=` sign assigns a value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses.  What am I missing here? https://codepen.io/ohem/pen/prMjYy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use getComputedStyle -

> The getComputedStyle() method gets all the actual (computed) CSS
>   property and values of the specified element.

```js
var red = document.getElementById("red");
var rd = window.getComputedStyle(red).getPropertyValue("opacity");
var green = document.getElementById("green");
if (rd == 0) {
  green.style.height = "200px";
}
```

```css
#red {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
}

#green {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="red">Red</div>
<div id="green">Green</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This looks like exactly what I was hoping for.

I didn't know about getComputedStyle().

Comment: This works perfectly in all my tests! I'm not sure why your comment was downvoted... Is there any downside to this method?  Thank you again for the amazing help.

Comment: Welcome @emma :-) Don't know why it is down-voted, but this is how you could check styled assigned to an element and that output can be further used with condition.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're explicitly setting opacity.  The following code should work:

```
if(red.style.opacity == 0){
   green.style.height = "200px";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  The height changes regardless of the opacity: https://codepen.io/ohem/pen/PKMZaZ